# Does stackoverflow.ru abuse Stack Overflow's name?

Tags: discussion, support, localization

I just found this russian question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711547/qt-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

There was a comment from one user which just pointed out to use stackoverflow.ru, I was confused in the first moment I just know the english and the Portuguese site [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), however stackoverflow.ru redirecty to a total differnt site (hashcode.ru), so I think there is going something wrong. What do you think about it?

Comment: Comment gone, question closed. The meta effect strikes again.

Comment: @JanDvorak that's true however that domain still exists.

Comment: I'm afraid this happens to plenty of sites...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The (now deleted) comment goes to `www.stackoverflow.ru`, which just returns an *empty* site.

`stackoverflow.ru` does indeed redirect to `hashcode.ru`, which is a Stack Overflow clone (one of many, all of which we are fine with, so long as they don't reuse our content, or, if they do, they also attribute it as we require).

The ownership and use of `stackoverflow.ru` could indeed be a problem.

**Update:** As Stack Exchange has acquired the owners of `hashcode.ru` and fully integrated that site into our network, we now own the `stackoverflow.ru` domain, and it redirects to our site.

---

As for the legal perspective of whether just anyone can use the name stackoverflow for a Q&A site for programmers? I am not a lawyer, but as far as I know, we don't hold a copyright / patent on the combination... and going to sue overseas for this... well... we have better ways to spend our time and money ;)

Now, I have not spoken to our lawyers about it, so could be off-base - these are simply my thoughts on the matter and I am not representing an official Stack Exchange stance.

Comment: Be sure to raise things like this with SE's lawyers. If you see another site doing programming Q&A and calling itself "Stack Overflow" and *don't* send them a cease-and-desist letter at the very least, my understanding is that that would mean you weren't defending your defacto trademark, which would invalidate it (make it impossible to defend in the future). Which SE may be fine with (I'd argue you shouldn't but...), but probably needs to make an actual decision about rather than something you slide into... (But IANAL either, and even if I were, I'm not *your* lawyer, so... :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - believe me, we do take it seriously.

Comment: Good good... :-)